# What's the point of instructions with only the REX prefix in 64bit mode?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers, instruction-set

For example one of the MOV has 2 versions, one with REX, one without (from Intel's doc) :

```
88 /r MOV r/m8, r8
REX + 88 /r MOV r/m8***, r8***

***In 64-bit mode, r/m8 can not be encoded to access the following byte registers if a REX prefix is used: AH, BH, CH, DH.
```

From what I understand, the 2 instructions are identical except the second one uses an additional byte and provides less options ... So basically it is useless.

What am I missing ?

Comment: The REX prefix can also be used for [efficient alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48046814/995714) even instructions that don't need one

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's to do with the encoding of the registers in the instruction. The bits available in the r/m part select from a set of registers - those registers change, depending upon the REX prefix:

Available 8-bit registers without REX prefix:

> AL, CL, DL, BL, AH, CH, DH, BH

Available 8-bit registers with REX prefix set:

> AL, CL, DL, BL, SPL, BPL, SIL, DIL, R8B, R9B, R10B, R11B, R12B, R13B, R14B, R15B

This is why Intel docs draw attention to the fact that you cannot select certain registers with the REX prefix set.

Comment: See Intel's SDM for full details (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/intel-sdm.html#inpage-nav-2) and other docs in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.  Also https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#REX_prefix

Answer (score 7):

It's not useless, but not overwhelmingly useful either.

A REX prefix changes `ah`, `ch,` `dh` and `bh` into `spl`, `bpl`, `sil` and `dil` (respectively). So while you cannot use the first set, you can use the second set.

Comment: I picked the other as answer because there is a little more info but thank you anyway